# window.open() inside multiple if conditions doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open

My javascript code is like this:

```
function openWindows() {

    if(A is true) {
      window.open(URL_A);
    }

    if(B is true) {
      window.open(URL_B);
    }

    and so on...

}
```

When my function is called, with all conditions true, random no. of windows open. Some times, all of them open but it happens randomly. What could be the issue? Am I losing the parent window reference? Why is this happening randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me.

Are you sure your popup blocker isn't stopping them? Many browsers don't allow you to trigger new windows without a click event or the browser will stop them.  Also, the browser usually allows one window per click event.

```
if(true) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
}

if(true) {
      window.open('http://www.google.com');
}

if(true) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
}

if(true) {
      window.open('http://www.google.com');
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2LJtv/ ( warning be prepared for 4 windows to open )

Comment: This worked. In the if conditions I was comparing booleans like if(var_a == true), instead, now I am using directly if(var_a) - and this works perfectly fine. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: @kiran: you may want to search for javascript `truthy` and `falsy`

Comment: Actually it did not work...:( since I am developing a chrome plugin, I used, chrome.tabs.create({url:url),});

Answer (score 2):

`is true` and `and so on...` is not legitimate JavaScript code.

---

> When my function is called, with all conditions true, random no. of windows open. Some times, all of them open but it happens randomly. What could be the issue?

Cannot answer w/o more information.

> Am I losing the parent window reference? Why is this happening randomly?

Cannot answer w/o more information.

---

Your question is interesting, but the pseudocode should work, provided the following evaluate to valid values:

- `A is true`
- `B is true`

And the following are valid variables that contain valid values:

- `URL_A`
- `URL_B`

Comment: This should probably be a comment. :P

Comment: @Trevor: haha I debated it, however if that is his actual code, this would be an acceptable answer.  I started to, but there was too much to put in a comment.